# Can clone put branches in seperate folders?

Tags: git

Im coming from SVN, where if I check out a branch, I have the option of putting the code into specific folder.  When I clone a repo in Git, then checkout a branch, im still in the same working folder.  Is this normal?

Lets say I have checked out a feature branch, added a few files and pushed them to the remote. Then I checkout the master branch again.  Do the new files added in the feature branch go away, or now show as changes that need to be added?

Comment: The files will be removed from your working folder and the files and their state from the master branch will be placed there instead.

Comment: You can, however, check out multiple branches at the same time using "worktrees". However, I suggest you not do that until you've grasped the fundamentals of git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not work the same way - moving between branches stays in the same working directory.

Adding or removing files, assuming the files are committed into the branch, will be correctly added or removed as you check out the different branches.

If you want separate directories, you'll need to clone the source repository multiple times, and check out different branches in each directory. This can be occasionally useful, but in practice is fighting the tool and will make things more difficult day-to-day.